# Can't get heroku work with rails 3.x postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I followed Heroku official guides to push rails project to [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/). The `application.rb` file is ok, I added `pg` gem and `database.yml` in the right way. When I push to heroku I get:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally
```

But when I open heroku via `heroku open` I get an error. I put heroku logs and get this.

```
Started GET "/" for 93.45.227.255 at 2012-10-11 13:28:04 +0000
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProductsController#index as HTML
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "products" does not exist
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"products"'::regclass
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET gift4.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=203ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 72ms
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"products"'::regclass
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:5:in `index'
2012-10-11T13:28:04+00:00 heroku[router]: GET gift4.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico d
```

So I tried

```
heroku run rake db:reset
```

And get this

```
Heroku client internal error.
!    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
!    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
    Backtrace:   /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.32.6/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `initialize'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.32.6/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `open'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.32.6/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:39:in `block in start'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.32.6/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:31:in `start'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.32.6/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:125:in `rendezvous_session'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.32.6/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:112:in `run_attached'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.32.6/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:21:in `index'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.32.6/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.32.6/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/heroku-2.32.6/bin/heroku:16:in `<top (required)>'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
                 /Users/francescochecco/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku run rake db:reset
    Version:     heroku-gem/2.32.6 (x86_64-darwin11.3.0) ruby/1.9.3 autoupdate
```

I tried everything. Anyone could help?

Comment: try updating heroku toolbelt with heroku update

Comment: Did upgrading the toolbelt work? The [status page](https://status.heroku.com/) has been green all day. If nothing works you might consider registering a ticket with Heroku. Also, which stack are you on (Celadon Cedar, perhaps?)

Comment: heroku update
Updating from 2.32.11... done, nothing to update

Answer (score 2):

Did you migrate the database? This error:

```
(PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "products" does not exist
```

...usually indicates that you have a table missing. In this case, your `products` table probably doesn't exist.

I agree that `db:reset` should load your schema for you, so this should resolve the above problem, theoretically. However, the timeout is weird, and maybe temporary.

Try to push your app again, then on your command line, try:

```
heroku run rake db:reset
```

...or

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

...and let me know what happens.

Also, what database is your app trying to use (I'm guessing Postgres)? The `production` section of your `database.yml` is typically ignored by heroku, as they inject their own `production` database section.

Comment: I tried to migrate and to reset as you suggested. i ger the same error. i tried to create a new app from scratch. same error. I Have ruby 1.9.3...and the latest rails gem.

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the heroku db with

```
$ heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm myapp
```

and then do `$ heroku restart`

see if that helps

then try to migrate

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile locally before you pushed?  If so a manifest.yml was generated and may be causing the error on the heroku side.  Its been a long time, but I used to precompile locally (not sure why) and I had errors like this...I think.  Don't precompile locally.  If you have ever precompiled locally go into your public directory and delete the generated assets folder.  Then push to heroku and see if it compiles remotely and clears your problem.